# PHP : mail() - send multiple subject

Tags: php

I have 2 contact forms on one page. But I want to send different topics with `php mail functions`.
When sending data from the first form, "Subject-1" is displayed, If in another form, "Subject-2" is displayed. How can I compare each form in a post request to set the correct subject

**First Form**

```
                    <form id="contact-form" method="POST" class="d-flex form footer-form">
                        <input type="text" class="simple-input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="text" class="simple-input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                        <textarea class="quession-input" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Your question"></textarea>
                        <div class="checkboks custom-sq">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checked-checkbox" name="myCheckboxes" id="box1" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            <label for="box1" class="checkboks-text"><?php echo the_field('checkbox_text', 'option'); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="danger-btn submit"><?php echo the_field('btn_send', 'option'); ?></button>
                    </form>
```

**Second Form**

```
            <form id="hy-form" method="POST" class="d-flex form">
                <input type="text" class="simple-input" name="hy_name" id="hy_name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="simple-input" name="hy_email" id="hy_email" placeholder="Email address">
                <textarea class="quession-input" id="hy_msg" name="hy_msg" placeholder="Your question"></textarea>
                <div class="checkboks custom-sq">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="myCheckboxesHy" class="checked-checkbox" checked="checked" value="true"/>
                    <label for="box3" class="checkboks-text"><?php echo the_field('checkbox_text', 'option'); ?></label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="danger-btn hy-submit"><?php echo the_field('btn_send', 'option'); ?></button>
            </form>
```

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_send_email', 'send_email');
function send_email() {

    $checkbox = $_POST['myCheckboxes'];
    if (isset($checkbox)) {
        echo $checkbox;
    }

    $checkbox_hy = $_POST['myCheckboxesHy'];
    if (isset($checkbox_hy)) {
        echo $checkbox_hy;
    }
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $hy_name = $_POST['hy_name'];
    $from = 'gtest@gtest.com';
    $to = 'gtest@gtest.com';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $hy_email = $_POST['hy_email'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    $hy_msg = $_POST['hy_msg'];
    $subject = 'Footer form: ' . $_POST['email'];
    $message .= (!empty($name)) ?  '<p><strong>User Name</strong> : ' . $name .'  </p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($email)) ?  '<p><strong>User Email</strong> : '. $email .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($msg)) ?  '<p><strong>User Message</strong> : '.$msg .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($checkbox)) ?  '<p><strong>Checkboxs</strong> : '.$checkbox .'</p>' : '';

    $message .= (!empty($hy_name)) ?  '<p><strong>User Name</strong> : '.$hy_name .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($hy_email)) ?  '<p><strong>User Email</strong> : '.$hy_email .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($hy_msg)) ?  '<p><strong>User Message</strong> : '.$hy_msg .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= (!empty($checkbox_hy)) ?  '<p><strong>Checkboxses</strong> : '.$checkbox_hy .'</p>' : '';


    $message .= (!empty($url)) ?  '<p><strong>Url:</strong> : '.$url .'</p>' : '';
    $message .= '</body></html>';
    echo mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    return  $msg;
    die();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I try this code, it's work, but right way ?

```
if ($hy_name) {
    $subject = 'HY form: ' . $_POST['email'];        
} elseif ($name) {
    $subject = 'Footer form: ' . $_POST['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

One is to add a hidden field:

In the first form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="the_first_form"/>
```

In the second form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="the_second_form"/>
```

In PHP then do

```
if ($_POST["form_name"] === "the_first_form") {
  $subject = "Subject for the first form";
} else {
  $subject = "another subject";
}
```

Sidenote: Be aware that the browser only submits one form.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, every browsers send only one form ?

Comment: The form you hit the submit button in, is transmitted. You will never get both forms at the same time unless you are doing it yourself in JavaScript.